# JTextArea making text invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want my JTextArea to show only the caret. I've setted my JTextArea to not opaque but I couldn't hide the text. How do I achieve this

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
text.setOpaque(false);//This doesn't make text transparent
```

Comment: _Invisible_ and _show_ seem contradictory. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you're doing. An image and the name of your platform/look & feel would be helpful, too.

Comment: Do you want to remove the text in the `JTextArea`, or simply keep the text but making it invisible (as in use the same font color as the background color of the `JTextArea`) ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to set the foreground color of the JTextarea the as the same as its background color.

Comment: It doesn't work for my purpose. Because what I want to do is, I will add a JTextArea in front of a JTextPane. this JTextPane will highlight my code. Whenever I change my text in JTextArea it will be appear on JTextPane in highlighted format. So if I just  set the color of text same as background color, I will still have a problem

Comment: @mayy00 Not sure I understand your question. hence I will post a comment: why don't you make your text color the same as the background? this will hide the text with minimal programming effort

Comment: @GETah because I want to see the highlighted text in background

Comment: *"I couldn't hide the text"*  Why would you want to?  What benefit does that provide to the end user?  It seems yet another 'unusable GUI' in the making.  :(

Comment: +1, this question added something to my knowledge, a very wise dirty hack :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
JTextArea a = new JTextArea();
a.setText("hello, world!");
a.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

seemed to work fine when I tested it, it made both set text and typed text invisible.

Comment: +1, wonderful thingy, you told me today, LOL wish I could upvote this a million times. Nice answer :-)

Comment: Probably even better if you use `a.setForeground( a.getBackground() );` iso hardcoded color